# How to use php's password_hash() method..?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, authentication, passwords

I'm getting password does not match when I login, 
when a user signup, I'm saving password as

```
$password = password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

when a user login I'm checking password like this,

```
    $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $this->db->select('password');
    $this->db->from('usersdetails');
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $passwordcheck = $query->row()->password;
    if (password_verify($passwordcheck, $hash)) {
       return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

BUT it always return password does not match..why?????
Any help is much appreciated...

Comment: `if (password_verify($passwordcheck, $hash))` you're checking against the `password_hash()` where you should be checking against whatever is in your db and user inputted password. and make sure the column length is 60+ when the hash was saved.

Comment: RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are supposed to check the raw unhashed password, as the `password_verify()` does the re-hashing of the raw password using the hash routine used when creating the hashed password.

If you look at the result of the `password_hash()` there is information stored in the hash about which hash routine was used to create this hash, and how it was generated

```
$password = 'FredsTheMan';

$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

if (password_verify($password, $hash)) { 
   return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Another common mistake in this area is not giving the column you use on the database table enough characters to hold the full result of the hash

The hash generated using PASSWORD_BCRYPT is 60 characters

```
$2y$12$QjSH496pcT5CEbzjD/vtVeH03tfHKFy36d4J0Ltp3lRtee9HDxY3K
```

Beware, when other hashes are providied in the furure, they may result in a  hash longer than 60 characters

So in short you code should be

```
$this->db->select('password');
$this->db->from('usersdetails');
$this->db->where('email', $email);
$this->db->limit(1);
$query = $this->db->get();
$pwd_from_db = $query->row()->password;

if (password_verify($this->input->post('password'), $pwd_from_db)) {
   return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: [You took the words right out of my mouth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35683537/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-method#comment59044498_35683537) *Smokey* ;-)

Comment: Afternoon Ralph @Fred-ii- Glad you brushed your teeth this morning

Comment: `$password` OP might think they still need to use `$password = password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_BCRYPT);` - should not that `$password` should be coming from their form input and that the password column length should be 60+ - Edit: ah you edited ;-) nice.

Comment: Amended as per your suggestion